# ShieldUI Chart Y Axis styling not working properly

Tags: shieldui

I'm evaluating ShieldUI for a client's application and I've run into an issue with setting styles on the Y axis header.  Below is the code from the view:

```
@(Html.ShieldChart(Model)
      .Name("chart")
      .PrimaryHeader(header => header.Text("")) //no header needed
      .Export(true) //turn on export
      .ChartLegend(legend => legend.Enabled(false)) //turn off legend since there's only 1 series
      .Tooltip(tooltip =>
               tooltip.ChartBound(true)
                   //turn on the axis marker tooltip thingy
                      .AxisMarkers(axisMarkers =>
                                   axisMarkers.Enabled(true).Mode(TooltipAxisMarkerMode.XY)
                                              .Width(1).ZIndex(3)
                   )
                      .CustomHeaderText("{point.pointName:MM-yyyy}")
                      .CustomPointText("{point.y:c}")
      )
      .AxisX(axisX => axisX
                          .CategoricalValues(model => model.Date)
                          .Title(title => title.Text("Month").Style(style => style.FontWeight(FontWeight.Bold)))
                          .AxisTickText(axisTickText => axisTickText.Format("{text:MM-yyyy}")))
      .AxisY(axisY => axisY
                          .Title(title => title.Text("Price").Style(style => style.FontWeight(FontWeight.Bold)))
                          .AxisTickText(axisTickText => axisTickText.Format("{text:c}")))
      .DataSeries(dataSeries => dataSeries.Line()
                                          .Data(model => model.Price)))
```

The bold setting on the x axis works fine, but I can't get bold or size to work on the Y axis.  It looks like there may be something wrong with the markup that gets generated.  Below are the two text elements from the markup:

```
<text x="432" y="375" style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#404040;font-weight:bold;fill:#404040;" zIndex="7" text-anchor="middle" visibility="visible"><tspan x="432">Month</tspan></text>

<text x="25" y="181" style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#636363;font-weight:bold;font:11px Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;fill:#636363;" zIndex="7" transform="rotate(270 25 181)" text-anchor="middle" visibility="visible"><tspan x="25">Price</tspan></text>
```

The first one works fine, the second one doesn't, and I notice that the way they define their font information is different (the first using font-family and font-size, the second using a single font setting.  If I copy (via firebug) the style definition from the x to the y, the y axis becomes properly bolded.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this a bug with the way ShieldUI generates the SVG?  If it is a bug, any chance of it being fixed any time soon?  I can think of several ways to work around the problem, but I'd rather leave hacks out if possible and just wait for a fix if one would be on the horizon.

Edit: I realized that I'd copied markup for the Y axis that didn't match the view code I'd included here, so I updated that.  After doing so, I realized that the tag is getting a "font:" style added at the end after it has already defined the family, size, etc.  That makes me think even more so that this is a bug with ShieldUI in how it generates that markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've identified a bug in the Shield UI JavaScript Chart component that also affected the ASP.NET and MVC wrappers. The behavior you're describing was due to an issue in the way font settings were applied to chart axis titles. In some situations, the Shield UI Chart applied a default `font` style that prevented settings like `fontSize` and `fontWeight` from getting applied.

The issue was fixed shortly after discovery and will be available in the upcoming **1.6.4** version of the Shield UI JavaScript suite expected in the coming week. The fix is compatible with all server-side wrappers, including ASP.NET MVC.